# Default TTL on table in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to add a default ttl to an existing  table in Cassandra (1.2)?

I'm not referring to existing data - as I understand it that can't be done without re-inserting the data. However can we set a ttl on the table so any new data coming in to the table has that ttl?

Modifying the application to insert ttl's with the data isn't an option unfortunately.

Comment: Just to update an old question, as Jim mentioned this is possible in 2.0. However it can't be done in 1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jim mentioned this is possible in 2.0. However i confirmed it can't be done in 1.x.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can alter the table to adjust the properties like this:

```
ALTER TABLE sometable WITH default_time_to_live = 10;
```

This would give newly inserted data a TTL of 10.

I'm not sure if that works back in 1.2, but it works in current releases.